# APIFunction with TextRecognize problems

Tags: wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy, api, apifunction, http-functions

I have a simple API that takes a recipe and returns the list of ingredients:

```
api = CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"img"->"Image"},
    (ResourceFunction["DeleteFailures"]@Map[Function[w, Interpreter["FoodType"][w]], Flatten @ TextRecognize[#img, "Word"]])&
], Permissions->"Public", IncludeDefinitions->True]
```

So here's the example I'm trying to make work:

```
recipe = CloudGet@"https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/fe25d585-acc3-4931-9223-da5ee1dce6bd";
```

[image]

The function inside the API works just fine locally (without the APIFunction & CloudDeploy) as you can see:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Function[{img}, ResourceFunction["DeleteFailures"]@Map[Function[w, 
     Interpreter["FoodType"][w]], Flatten@TextRecognize[img, "Word"]]][recipe]]
```

[image]

But when deployed as an API in the Wolfram Cloud, *it refuses to return anything,* how can I get this to work?

**What I've Tried**

A simple POST request with `URLExecute` gives a 408 error:

```
AbsoluteTiming[URLExecute[api, <|"img"->recipe|>, TimeConstraint->\[Infinity]]]
```

[image]

Another attempt with the *obsolete-but-still-super-useful* `URLFetch` with multi-part data gives a 503 error (btw, does anyone know how to accomplish this without using an obsolete symbol?):

```
AbsoluteTiming[URLFetch[api, "Method" -> "POST",  "MultipartElements" -> {{"img", "image/jpeg"} -> ExportString[recipe, "JPEG"]}]]
```

[image]

Comment: At a minimum, it would be helpful to know if anyone is able to run my code and what results/error they see?

Comment: TextRecognize seems to crash in the public cloud. If I run this simple example in an interactive cloud notebook the kernel quits:
`((TextRecognize[ChanVeseBinarize[#1, "TargetColor" -> Black]] &)[
Import["https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"]]) === "Google" `
And that is the reason your APIFunction does not work.
( I've chose that example because it evaluates to True both on Mathematica 12.0 and 12.1, and because it works in a WEPC 1.54.1 environment (with 12.0) )

Comment: Right using TextRecognize crashes on Public cloud. We will investigate this. Thanks.

Comment: `TextRecognize ` crash is now fixed on Public cloud.

Comment: @dsingh Yes, but the URLExecute api request still times-out...

Comment: I think that is because of sending large data in the request parameter. The other example where you are sending the input as MultipartElements kind of worked for me.

Comment: @dsingh the URLFetch looks like it works slowly, but then URLExecute should work too, or at least message what the issue is no?